# Gender neutral Mx. without a name

Tags: grammaticality, formal-language

I would like to hear from native speakers if it's okay to use **Mx.** in a formal email to a person whose sex you don't know? Is **Mx.** used in English?

P.s. What to write after **Mx.** if you don't know his name either?

I was thinking of **Mx. Stranger**.

Comment: Could you find an example using "Mx."? If not then probably not.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mx_(title)   See the "Usage" section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't know the gender or name of the person you are writing to, I would just use **Dear Sir or Madam**.

**Mx.** is not a widely recognized title in the English language.

Comment: This is so much better than “Mx. Stranger”

Comment: Not a *widely* recognized title? That's understating it just a bit, I think! Good suggestion though on the substitute.

Comment: "To whom it may concern" is also an acceptable salutation.